# Solving $y'=\frac{xye^{\frac xy}+y^2}{x^2 e^{\frac xy}-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ordinary differential equation $y'=\dfrac{xye^{\frac xy}+y^2}{x^2 e^{\frac xy}-y^2}$ Which can be written as $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{(\frac xy)^2 e^{\frac xy}-1}{\frac xye^{\frac xy}+1}$. By using the substitution $v=\frac xy$ we have,

$$v'y+v=\dfrac{v^2e^v-1}{ve^v+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad y\frac {dv}{dy}=\dfrac{-v-1}{ve^v+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad -\frac{dy}y=\dfrac{ve^v+1}{v+1}dv$$
Hence $\int\dfrac{ve^v+1}{v+1}dv=-\ln|y|+c$. So I have to evaluate the integral,

$$\int\dfrac{ve^v+1}{v+1}dv=\int \frac1{v+1}+\frac{(v+1)e^v-e^v}{v+1}dv=\ln|v+1|+e^v-\int\frac{e^v}{v+1}dv$$

But I don't know how to evaluate the last integral. According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316933/how-to-calculate-int-dfrac-et-1tdt?noredirect=1) I can rewrite it in the form $\frac1e\int\dfrac{e^t}tdt$ which still doesn't have a closed-form. On the other hand the book that I'm reading provide only the final solution for the ODE which is $(\frac xy-1)e^{\frac xy}=c-\ln y$. But I don't know how to get this answer and what am I missing in my approach.

Comment: Did you differentiate the solution and see whether it matches the question?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Good idea. I'm doing it right now.

Comment: I just differentiate and got $y'=\dfrac{xy e^{\frac xy}}{xe^{\frac xy}-y^2}$ ! So it seems $y^2$ in the numerator of the equation is just a typo.

Comment: You are totally correct. $\to +1$